# Facebook font problem

Tags: wine, fonts, facebook

I installed Wine HQ for Ubuntu. And then Ubuntu installed some Windows fonts like arial and e.t.c. After restarting computer I saw that Facebook font changed. How can I resolve it?

Comment: is this happening in a browser?

Comment: To what extent is this a problem? Do these new fonts look ugly? Is the rendering really bad? Could you share a screenshot of a small part of the screen and add it to the question?

Answer (score 1):

My answer assumes you did not have fonts like Tahoma, Arial, etc installed before and that this is happening in any browser.

Facebook uses the following fonts mostly:

> 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif

Those are used in the order provided. If Lucida Grande is not available, it will use Tahoma, then Verdana, then Arial, then falls back to a default sans-serif font, most likely DejaVu Sans or Ubuntu. What likely happend was that with installing Windows fonts those became available to your browser for rendering Facebook.

Does it bother you? You could install Lucida Grande to have Facebook show up as intended by Facebook. Alternatively, you could disallow websites from setting their own fonts and have all the sites fall back to Firefox' default fonts (and sizes) in Firefox' settings (contents, advanced in the fonts section, tick the box there)